# Can we create sql DB server backup on different database(free database)?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have SQL database with huge amount of data. I want to create backup DB server using free databsase (e.g.Mysql) which will be back up server of SQL database. How can I do this ?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this? Disaster recovery? Application changes will be required to switch from SQL Server to MySQL.

Comment: The answer is the same as the question.

Answer (score 2):

If your primary db is on SQL Server and backup is MySQL you can copy table by table only.

I would recommend using SSIS package to copy data between DBs and schedule the SSIS package as job so backup is done automatically.

Note: this copies data only. Your Views, Stored Procs wont get copied and they wont be compatible too.

Plan B : You can use FREE SQLServer Express edition as backup server (instead of MySQL) and do a traditional SQLServer backup (one .bak per db) and restore it in SQL Server Express. This way your script will be backed up.

Hope this helps